# How to retrieve human readable data from MMA8451 accelerometer using nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing, iot, accelerometer

I receive via serial port data from an accelerometer module MMA8451.
I'm using nodejs to capture data from serial and do the parsing work.
The payload I get seems to be an hex

```
d40 14fc 88c0
540 800 c8c0
840 340 20c0
b0fc c80 d8c0
200 700 68c0
800 480 acc0
100 c0 c0c0
```

Which I suppose are the three axis values
If I simply try to convert in binary and the decimal using hex2bin and parseint I get values that are ranging from 0 to 256 but they don't make sense.

```
XYZ 248 16 184
XYZ 252 64 192
XYZ 128 64 192
XYZ 0 192 192
XYZ 252 64 192
XYZ 0 192 192
XYZ 64 0 192
XYZ 0 128 192
XYZ 128 64 192
XYZ 0 0 192
```

How I can get human readable values from this data?

**UPDATE:**

As NikaTheEngineer pointed out I've looked at the accelerometer datasheet https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8451Q.pdf (see chapter 5.2) and the data I'm receiving seems to be the raw data from those registers OUT_X_MSB, OUT_X_LSB, OUT_Y_MSB, OUT_Y_LSB, OUT_Z_MSB

Those are 14bit so this imply some sort of data manipulation with by bites shift am I correct?

If I print the stream directly from the serialport (removing the hex conversion) I receive this kind of payload

```
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 36 38 66 63 20 34 38 30 20 61 38 63 30 20 31 30 38 33 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 37 34 66 63 20 39 38 30 20 61 38 63 30 20 31 30 38 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 38 66 63 20 35 63 30 20 37 30 63 30 20 31 30 38 35 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 61 63 66 63 20 63 34 30 20 63 38 63 30 20 31 30 38 36 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 37 30 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 37 30 63 30 20 31 30 38 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 36 30 66 63 20 36 38 66 63 20 66 34 63 30 20 31 30 38 38 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 63 38 66 63 20 61 30 30 20 37 30 63 30>
<Buffer 20 31 30 38 39 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 30 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 62 63 63 30 20 31 30 39 30 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 37 34 66 63 20 34 30 30 20 61 38 63 30 20 ... 6 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 35 30 66 63 20 34 63 30 20 35 38 63 30 20 31 30 39 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 38 63 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 37 38 63 30 20 31 30 39 33 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 36 30 66 63 20 38 30 30 20 62 30 63 30 20 31 30 39 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 32 38 66 63 20 33 30 30 20 37 38 63 30 20 31 30 39 35 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 64 38 66 63 20 37 30 30 20 37 30 63 30 20 31 30 39 36 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 34 30 66 63 20 61 30 30 20 64 30 63 30 20 31 30 39 37 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 39 63 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 37 30 63 30 20 31 30 39 38 0d 0a ... 25 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 62 63 66 63 20 36 34 30 20 39 38 63 30>
<Buffer 20 31 31 30 30 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 34 38 66 63 20 36 38 30 20 38 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 31 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 34 66 63 20 32 63 30 20 61 30 63 30 20 ... 6 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 34 38 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 36 38 63 30 20 31 31 30 33 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 32 38 66 63 20 61 30 30 20 61 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 35 30 66 63 20 39 38 30 20 38 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 35 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 36 34 66 63 20 31 63 30 20 37 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 36 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 33 30 66 63 20 38 38 30 20 61 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 38 66 63 20 62 38 30 20 35 34 63 30 20 31 31 30 38 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 64 34 66 63 20 63 30 30 20 64 30 63 30 20 31 31 30 39 0d 0a 65 ... 48 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 66 38 66 63 20 37 38 30 20 34 34 63 30 20 31 31 31 32 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 31 30 66 63 20 38 30 30 20 38 38 63 30 20 31 31 31 33 0d 0a ... 49 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 66 30 66 63 20 35 30 30 20 38 38 63 30 20 31 31 31 36 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 34 38 66 63 20 34 34 30 20 61 38 63 30 20 31 31 31 37 0d 0a ... 25 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 32 38 66 63 20 38 63 30 20 62 38 63 30 20 31 31 31 39 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 32 38 66 63 20 36 38 30 20 39 30 63 30 20 31 31 32 30 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 65 38 66 63 20 66 38 30 20 32 38 63 30 20 31 31 32 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 63 38 66 63 20 39 30 30 20 64 34 63 30 20 31 31 32 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 35 34 66 63 20 36 34 30 20 66 38 63 30 20 31 31 32 33 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 38 30 66 63 20 37 30 30 20 33 38 63 30 20 31 31 32 34 0d 0a ... 50 more bytes>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 35 63 66 63 20 32 30 30 20 63 63 63 30 20 31 31 32 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 64 38 66 63 20 35 38 30 20 36 30 63 30 20 31 31 32 38 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 66 30 66 63 20 38 30 30 20 61 38 63 30 20 31 31 32 39 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 65 30 66 63 20 64 63 30 20 62 30 63>
<Buffer 30 20 31 31 33 30 0d 0a 65 33 38 30 20 36 30 66 63 20 36 63 30 20 39 38 63 30 20 31 31 33 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 33 30 66 63 20 35 30 30 20 36 30 63 30 20 31 31 33 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 62 30 66 63 20 64 30 30 20 63 34 63 30 20 31 31 33 33 0d 0a>
```

I guess this is the stream of raw data in bytes.

I suppose the first step is to distinguish every single chunk samples composed by xmsb-xlsb ymsb-ylsb zmsb-zlsb, but at this point I have no idea how to do it, there should be some kind of delimiter?

I need to work blindly on the buffer just trusting the datastructure pointed in the datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to convert hex number to binary. Function parseInt can convert hex to decimal.
[Check this out!](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp#:%7E:text=The%20parseInt()%20function%20parses,number%20to%20a%20decimal%20number.)

Secondly, if you parsed your data correctly, it should not be in range(0, 256); The last hex number you recived is **c0c0**, which in decimal is **49344** (unsigned value).
[Go ahead and test it on this site!](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html)

Lastly, are you sure you are reading data from hardware correctly? I found the datasheet of the accelerometer and it is written there that data is stored in 14 bits for each axis. The highest unsigned value in hex that can be stored in 14 bits is **3FFF**, which is far less than some of your data; for example: c0c0, acc0...
[You can find the datasheet here!](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8451Q.pdf)

If u let me know how u read data from the hardware, I might be able to help you :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you made me realize I've to do some data manipulation. Indeed I'm getting data via serial using serialport nodejs module. What I get before the hex is indeed a buffer or raw data like this:

<Buffer 65 33 38 30 20 34 38 66 63 20 31 38 30 20 63 34 63 30 20 38 30 38 33 39 32 0d 0a> 

Looking the datasheet it seem a check of 6bytes composed by OUT_X_MSB, OUT_X_LSB, OUT_Y_MSB, OUT_Y_LSB, OUT_Z_MSB.
But at this point I'm a bit at loss since I never worked on binary, buffers, shifting, ect...

Comment: Okay, I see you use nodejs module but what I want to know is what sends this data to the computer. What microcontroller do you use to read the data from the accelerometer? If you use Arduino or anything like it, there is an official library that converts the data in human readable form. If you are able to use this lib, you won't have to do data manipulation on your own, you will recive human readable data for the node app then to use however you want it.